# Show a Div Progress indicator in IE8 with jquery show function inside a button click event that does asyncronous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a progress indicator in my page:

```
<div id="loaderDiv" align="center" class="ProgressIndicator" style="display:none;"></div>
```

A css class for the progress indicator:

```
.ProgressIndicator 
{
    z-index: 9002;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  background-image: url(../Images/ajax-loaderGrayBackground.gif);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*cursor: wait;*/
  background-color:#DBDADA;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%

}
```

And a function (CreateDataGrid)that I am invoking inside a click event handler. This function creates a jqxGrid and calls an asynchronous ajax method.

```
<!-- Function code including jqxGrid creation and dataAdapter -->
var dataAdapter = _masterDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,
{
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   async: true,
   cache: true,
   formatData: function (data) {

       // get parameters here
       var personID = $('#<%= PersonNameDropDownList.ClientID %>').val();
       var cityID = $('#<%= CityDropDownList.ClientID %>').val();

       //  set the data to be passed to the server for parameters
       data = {
           personID: personID, 
           cityID: cityID
       };

       return data;
   },
   downloadComplete: function (edata, textStatus, jqXHR) {

       if (edata.d == null) {

           alert("An error has occurred during the Retrieve process.");
       }
       else if (edata.d.length >= 100)
           showRowLimitLabel = true;

   }
});

function CreateGridData() {

    // reset variables that shows information label
    showRowLimitLabel = false;
    showInactiveAccountLabel = false;

    $(".ProgressIndicator").show();

    // if is first time Retrieve button is clicked create the jqxGrid
    if (firstTimeRetrieveIsClicked == true) {
        firstTimeRetrieveIsClicked = false;

        // Creation of the grid
        $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid(
           {
               width: 1500,
               columnsheight: 30,
               pagesize: 25,
               pagesizeoptions: ['10', '25', '50', '100'],
               selectionmode: 'singlerow',
               columnsresize: true,
               enabletooltips: true,
               rowdetails: true,
               source: dataAdapter, // in the 
               initrowdetails: initrowdetails,
               rowdetailstemplate: { rowdetails: "<div id='grid' ></div>", rowdetailsheight: 200, rowdetailshidden: true },

               columns:
                   [
                       { text: 'Type', datafield: 'Type', width: 60  },
                       { text: 'Business', datafield: 'Business', width: 90, cellsalign: 'left' },
                       // some other columns
                   ]
           });
    }
    else {
        // if not is the first time then just call event that retrieve data
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata');
    }

    $(".ProgressIndicator").hide();
}
```

Button and click event declaration:

```
<!-- In Html -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-success text-left " id="RetrieveButton" value="Retrieve Summary" style="width:100px;"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Search</button>

<!-- Inside document ready -->
$("#RetrieveButton").click(function (event) {
      CreateDataGrid();                   
});
```

Things I did:

The progress indicator have a display value of block. Visibility of visible after the invocation of
`$(".ProgressIndicator").show()` inside `CreateDataGrid` function, but doesn't show.

Values of properties of ProgressIndicator just before calling show function inside CreateDataGrid checked in debugger watches

```
$(".ProgressIndicator").is(":visible")  false
$(".ProgressIndicator").css("display")  "none"
$(".ProgressIndicator").css("position") "fixed"
$(".ProgressIndicator").height()    481
$(".ProgressIndicator").css("z-index")  999999
$(".ProgressIndicator").width() 1670
```

Values of properties of ProgressIndicator just after calling show function inside CreateDataGrid checked in debugger watches

```
$(".ProgressIndicator").is(":visible")  true
$(".ProgressIndicator").css("display")  "block"
$(".ProgressIndicator").css("position") "fixed"
$(".ProgressIndicator").height()    481
$(".ProgressIndicator").width() 1670
$(".ProgressIndicator").css("z-index")  999999
```

Please any help/advice how to show the progress indicator would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like either a z-index issue, or that the indicator has either no height or no width (or both).

Comment: I'll check that right now and give you a feedback Thanks

Comment: I think my problem is that the browser doesnt show the indicator because it is doing other tasks in the UI thread which blocks the execution, like creating the Grid and doing the AJAX call to fetch the data. How I can show inmediatly the ProgressIndicator and keep it spinning?